# Validação com Java Script

Tags: javascript

Caros;

Criei uma função em Java Script, onde esta função tem o intuito de pegar a data atual e mediante a esta data, conforme o usuário selecionar a bandeira de seu cartão, calcular se a fatura será inserida na tabela do mês atual ou no próximo mês, conforme a data de vencimento e data de fechamento dela.

Segue função:

```
 <script>
function finance() {

var dtcompra = document.getElementById("payment").value;
var datacompra = new Date(dtcompra);
var diacompra = datacompra.getDate();
var mespgto = document.getElementById("mespgto");
var itemSelecionado = mespgto.options[mespgto.selectedIndex].value;

var diamanualnubank = 25; // Vencimento Nubank
var diamanualamex = 15; // Vencimento Amex
var diamanualsantanderplatinum = 17; // Vencimento Santander Plantinum

// Função para retornar a data Atual
var data = new Date();
var dia = data.getDate();
   if (dia.toString().length == 1)
      dia = "0"+dia;
var mes = data.getMonth()+1
    if (mes.toString().length == 1)
    mes = "0"+mes;
var ano = data.getFullYear();  
//var data = ano+"/"+mes+"/"+dia;


if (itemSelecionado == 'nubank' && diacompra < 18) {


document.getElementById('maturity').value = ano+"/"+(data.getMonth()+1)+"/"+diamanualnubank;

    } else {
    document.getElementById('maturity').value = ano+"/"+(data.getMonth()+2)+"/"+diamanualnubank;

  return false;
}

if (itemSelecionado == 'amex' && diacompra > 10 &&  diacompra < 30) 

document.getElementById('maturity').value = ano+"/"+(data.getMonth()+1)+"/"+diamanualamex;

    else  {
    document.getElementById('maturity').value = ano+"/"+(data.getMonth()+2)+"/"+diamanualamex;

        return false;
}


if (itemSelecionado == 'santanderplatinum' && diacompra < 10) 

document.getElementById('maturity').value = ano+"/"+(data.getMonth()+1)+"/"+diamanualsantanderplatinum;

    else  {
    document.getElementById('maturity').value = ano+"/"+(data.getMonth()+2)+"/"+diamanualsantanderplatinum;

        return false;
}


}
</script>
```

Se a data atual for dia 10/09/2016 por ex e selecionar amex, deveria preencher o input do vencimento para 2016/09/15, se a data atual for maior que 10, o preenchimento deste input deveria ser 2016/10/15. Simulando aqui, o preenchimento está sendo com a data de vencimento do Nubank 2016/10/25. Não estou encontrando onde estou errando na logica.Não sou muito bom com Java Script e por isso recorro a vocês.

Conto com a ajuda de vocês. Obrigado.

Comment: Ao executar este código com o console de desenvolvedor aberto, que erro você recebe?

Comment: Olá Ifarroco, não recebo erros, acredito que é algum problema de lógica mesmo. Ele executa, porem com as datas erradas.

Comment: Se possível crie um https://jsfiddle.net com a parte html, pois o seu código faz referência a esses elementos. Além disso, adicione alguns "console.log()" ao longo da sua lógica. Por exemplo: antes dos if's, coloque console.log('o item selecionado é', itemSelecionado , 'e o dia de compra é ',diacompra ). Assim você pode saber quais parâmetros estão sendo usados.

Comment: Está pouco claro o problema que estás a ter... é isto que queres? https://jsfiddle.net/0ffd56kz/

Comment: Olá Sergio, sim, com seu código resolveu meu problema. Muito agradecido . Ps: Tentei entender sua logica para meu aprendizado e não consegui. Quando tiver um tempo e puder, teria como comentar ele explicando o que o mesmo faz para eu entender. Não sou muito bom em programação e teria interesse de entender sua logica. Vi que criou um array na variável (dataPagamento), porem não usou a variável e apontou o array direto no value do campo. Tinha lido bastante que em um IF em java script era utilizado dentro de um bloco "parenteses", porem em cada IF seu, foi usado dois parenteses. Grato.